# MAMP 1045 error on system boot only

Tags: mysql, mamp, lamp

My issue appears to be related to this unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219839/mamp-1045-error

I wasn't sure if I could comment there or if I had to start a new question, so sorry in advance if I'm not posting in the right spot.

Anyway, MAMP is in my startup items so it will open automatically when I boot OSX. (I actually have it launching via Delayed Launcher -- I wondered if it failed because it was booting too early, but it doesn't matter if it boots ASAP or after 30 seconds, it still has this issue.) When MAMP starts up after a system reboot, it gives me the following error:

> Checking MySQL databases failed
>
> Error message:
>
> /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying
>   to connect

The MAMP indicator lights show that Apache Server and MySQL Server are on. If I go to localhost, it shows the default MAMP "The virtual host was set up successfully" page instead of the actual virtual host I have mapped to localhost, and none of my vhosts work.

**If I click Ok, then click Stop Servers, then click Start Servers, it starts up no problem and I can use MAMP as usual. 
This only happens when I boot my OS, MAMP always works again when I restart MAMP itself.**

This is my mysql_error_log.err:

```
121105 10:15:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
121105 10:15:32 [Warning] You have forced lower_case_table_names to 0 through a command-line option, even though your file system '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' is case insensitive.  This means that you can corrupt a MyISAM table by accessing it with different cases. You should consider changing lower_case_table_names to 1 or 2
121105 10:15:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121105 10:15:32 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121105 10:15:32 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
121105 10:15:32 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121105 10:15:32 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121105 10:15:32 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121105 10:15:32 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121105 10:15:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121105 10:15:34 InnoDB: 1.1.5 started; log sequence number 1595675
121105 10:15:34 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
121105 10:15:34 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.9'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

I checked that my user name and password are correct in all the scripts in the /Applications/MAMP/bin folder (it is) and even reset it using

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/mysql4/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password <NEWPASSWORD>
```

to ensure that it really was the correct password. I also followed the previous answerer's comment about running

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

which executed fine but didn't solve the problem.

It doesn't matter if I have MAMP set to use the default Apache/MySQL ports or the default MAMP ports, so I have it set as the former.

Any ideas?? MAMP works again when I stop and start it, but it's really annoying to have to go through that process every time I boot up or restart my computer, since you have to put in your password whenever you stop MAMP. :/

**Edit:**

Uninstalled/reinstalled MAMP and it's still doing the same thing, except now it's asking for my password when it launches, too.

Comment: you should NOT be using the root account for anything public-facing. it's a major security risk.always always ALWAYS use a minimum-privilege account for such things.

Comment: It's only accessible within my local network; it's for development only.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/Applications/MAMP/bin/checkMysql.sh` in your text editor and change `-proot` to `-p [yourpass]`